# How to add a new pair of (key,value) to every subarray of a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

Let's imagine that I have a Json like this:

```
{
   0: {
      id: "1",
      usr: "pimba"
   },
   1: {
      id: "2",
      usr: "aloha"
   },
   ...
   100: {
      id: "3",
      usr: "pruu"
   }
}
```

I need to add a new (key,value) pair for EVERY subArray. Is it possible without using `foreach` ? Maybe some sort of function that already apply a certain fucntion to every subarray ?
I need to add the (key: value) after `usr: value`.

OBS: The set (key,value) that I want to add, in this case, will always be the same.

The result I need:

```
{
   0: {
      id: "1",
      usr: "pimba"
      synced: true
   },
   1: {
      id: "2",
      usr: "aloha"
      synced: true
   },
   ...
   100: {
      id: "3",
      usr: "pruu"
      synced: true
   }
}
```

Comment: what subarray??

Comment: where is your sub array?

Comment: The `0, 1, 2` aren't a set of associative arrays ? They are all inside an array, right ? So they are the subarrays. No?

Comment: Sounds like you got some things mixed up with php. What you have are objects whose properties is another object.

Comment: @Chris Guess you're right. Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
let a = {
    0: {
       id: "1",
       usr: "pimba"
    },
    1: {
       id: "2",
       usr: "aloha"
    },
    3: {
       id: "3",
       usr: "pruu"
    }
 }

 let b = Object.values(a).map(newKeyValue => {
    newKeyValue.newKey = "newValue"
    console.log(newKeyValue)
 })
```

First of all, what you call an "array" is actually an "object".

And objects have two very very cool methods.

`Object.keys` returns an array of all keys of the object.

`Object.values` returns an array of all values of the object.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! If I want to add `synced : true` after `usr: value`, altering `a`. Does it work in the same away ? trying it right now.

Comment: hey @PlayHardGoPro, I have no idea how the rest of your code looks like, no idea what `synced:true` is ... You can `edit` your question with the rest of your code, I will take a look. Btw, if you find my answer helpful you can mark it as the right answer. ;)

Comment: I updated the question with the end result that I need. Thank you!

Comment: well, @PlayHardGoPro it's the same then. 
`newKeyValue.synced = true` ;) Try it out and let us know.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro, awesome, dude! :) Glad you made it work! Now, don't forget to play around with `Object.keys()`, too. :) Also, besides `.map()`, you can also check out `.filter()` and `.reduce()` ;)